# Shared Memory between two processes after exec

Tags: c, linux, fork, system-calls, shared-memory

Parent:

```
shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, (1 << 16), IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0777);
setenv("SOME_ENV_VAR",stringof(shm_id);
if(fork()=0){
    execve(some_path,argv);
}
```

Child:

```
int shm_id = atoi(getenv("SOME_ENV_VAR"));
int *shared_mem = (int*)shmat(shm_id,0,NULL);
if(!shared_mem)
  return;
shared_mem[0]++;
```

I want to edit the shared memory in the child. Any reasons why this should not work? I am allocating the shared mem block via shmget in the Parent.Im placing the shm_id as an env variable for the child to read it after the fork and exec.

In the child, I am reading the proper shm_id then trying to get a pointer to the shared memory via shmat. In my code I have verified the shm_id in Parent and Child are the same... Any ideas?

Comment: I see at least one bug on every single line of both code samples, but the basic outline of the code is correct, except that you need to call `shmat` in the parent as well as in the child (do this _after_ the `fork`). If you want more help than that, please provide us with complete programs that we can compile and run for ourselves, and tell us in excruciating detail what actually happened when you ran them, and how that wasn't what you expected.

Comment: N.B. New programs should use [`shm_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) and friends instead of `shmget` and friends.

Comment: The shmat() call should be shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0).

Comment: @gblaster, have you done this task? Please tell me, what issue you had apart from function call parameters disorder. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `key_t` argument to `shmget` is not the same as the identifier that that function returns.  It’s not sensible to substitute one for the other.

However, if you change that and communicate the *shmid* instead of the *key*, your basic approach will work.

The *shmid* is a system-wide global identifier, and `shmat` will succeed if you have the appropriate process permissions, even if you are an unrelated process.  (And, even if you are related, an `execve` will detach any shared memory segments, requiring an explicit re-attach.)

Note that the spec is not terribly explicit about this, saying that ["[e]ach individual shared memory segment ... shall be identified by a unique positive integer, called ... a shared memory identifier, *shmid*."](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_07_01).

Comment: The return value of `shmget`, assuming that call succeeds, is a "shared memory identifier", which is the correct thing to pass to `shmat`.  However, it is not clear to me whether POSIX/XSI permits a "shared memory identifier" to be serialized and deserialized across process boundaries as OP is doing.  It doesn't say you can, but it doesn't say you can't either.

Comment: @zwol. The shmat in the child does not fail. It tries to give me a valid pointer... Ofc its different than the parent since I now have a new process address space in the child but I feel like this should work...

Comment: @gblaster I stand by everything I said in my comment on your question, _except_ that I am now unsure whether it's 100% kosher to transfer the return value of `shmget` from one process to another.  But if `shmat` does not fail in the child, that seems unlikely to be the issue.

Comment: @zwol upon further reading and testing, I think this is permissible by the spec.  Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

On OS level segments are identified by the *key*, the *ID* is local to a process only. Each process needs to do a *get* (passing them same key) and an *at* to use the memory.

An example here: http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/shm/shmat.html